# Local symmetry and General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, locality

First I want to consider an example of 1D motion. Lagrange equation:

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0 $$

If we transform $ L \rightarrow L+a $ with $a$ a is constant, the equation of motion remains unchanged. This is global symmetry.

To obtain local symmetry we want when transforming $L \rightarrow L+a(x) $ we still have the same equation. To obtain that we introduce the "total derivative":

$$\frac{Df}{dt} = \frac{df}{dt} +  \frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$$

Then the equantion of motion would be unchanged under any local transformation:

$$\frac{D}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = 0$$

$\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$ is considered related to the geometry of 1D space.

I see $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}$ is similar to the Christoffel symbols in general relativity.

Is there anyway to construct General Relativity by demanding local symmetry like this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand well your setup. After the definition of of your "total derivative" you are including a definite function $a(x)$, a sort of gauge field. What you meant is that The new equation of motion is thus invariant under the combined transformations $L\rightarrow L+b(x)$ and $a(x)\rightarrow a(x)+b(x)$, where $b(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$, right? If so, $a(x)$ is pure gauge in the sense that you can set it to zero everywhere once and for all with such a transformation, just pick $b(x)=-a(x)$.

Comment: At the moment I'm quite confusing. I just see a similarity with General Relativity Equation. Technically I don't really understand the gauge theory very much. I just need a sense of idea. :)